# Sitecore 10.1 publish to web error

Tags: publishing, migration

We have upgraded to `Sitecore 10.1 from Sitecore 8.2`.

When publishing some of the items to the `Web database`, I am getting the following error.

```
Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Data.SitecoreContentTestStore.GetTestVariableID(RenderingReference reference)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Data.SitecoreContentTestStore.GetMultivariateTestVariable(RenderingReference reference, Language language)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.XConnect.Integration.Services.ContentTestingService.GetDatasources(RenderingReference rendering, Language language)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.AddRenderingDataSourceReferences(Item item, PublishOptions options)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.GetReferencedItems(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.GetItemReferences(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.GetItemReferencesProcessor.Process(PublishItemContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.GetItemReferencesPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Is this happened with anyone and what is the fix for this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Previously I've migrated renderings and content with custom scripts and as a result, I had under `MySite - Presentation - Partial Designs` an invalid rendering visible only at `Presentation - Details - Edit controls`.

[image: invalid rendering]

The fix was to delete invalid rendering.